# Barplot in R: change the order and control labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have small data and I want to get bar-plot. I managed to graph the data. However, I have two questions.

1) I want to make the bars to be plotted in order according to the X-axis, not according the values. The x-axis is a range like : <40,100-500,500-1000, .....

some values like 40-100 is greater than 500-1000, it is plotted at the end. I want the bars to be based on the values of X-axis.

2) How do I control the position of the label value on each bar.

Here is my data from `dput`:

```
structure(list(range = structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("<40", "100-500", "1000-1468", "1469-1479", "1480-1500", 
"40-100", "500-1000"), class = "factor"), values = c(100L, 10000L, 
1000L, 505L, 2000L, 50L, 5000L)), .Names = c("range", "values"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

here is my code:

```
DF$X<-NULL
colnames(DF)<-c("Size","occurances")
gr2<- ggplot(DF, aes(x =Size , y= occurances))+ 
      geom_bar(aes(fill=Size),stat="identity") +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%0.0f", occurances)),
            y = occurances+0.25, x=Size),
           size = 5, face="bold",position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,colour="gray19",face="bold"),
            axis.text.y=element_text(colour="gray19",size=12,face="bold"))+
      theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 2))+
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("<40","40-100","100-500","500-1000","1000-1468","1469-  1479","1480-1500"),expand=c(0,0) )+
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.008,0.5))+
      guides(fill=FALSE)
      print(gr2)
```

Any suggestions !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DF$Size <- reorder(DF$Size, seq_along(DF$Size))
gr2<- ggplot(DF, aes(x =Size , y= occurances))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Size),stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%0.0f", occurances)),
                y = occurances+0.25, x=Size),
            size = 5, face="bold", vjust=-.8) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,colour="gray19",face="bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="gray19",size=12,face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 2))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.1,0))+
  guides(fill=FALSE)
print(gr2)
```

[image]

The key thing is to re-order your factor levels so that they actually are in increasing order (here I took advantage of the fact that your `DF` was already sorted in that order).  Then you can use `vjust` in `geom_text` to get the alignment right.  Note I also messed with `expand` with the y scale.  Also, got rid of your `scale_x_discrete` call as I think you were trying to use that to change the ordering, but that isn't necessary if you get the factor levels right.

As an aside, how did you generate the buckets? You should consider using `cut`, as that should set up your levels in the correct order.

Comment: That's Okay. But do you know how to make the graph supports black and white so it would be readable after print. I have tried the following:  "scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = .9)"